# Value not getting assigned to array element Bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I am working on the below script.

1. I don't understand why I am unable to assign the value to the array and when I print the array elements I only get arr[0], the rest of elements are empty
2. Is there a more efficient way to match  l_num between fields rt_h and rt_f extracted from rt_facts file?

> $ bash -version
> GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

```
$ cat rt_facts
T5 1 2:8 47:9 44
T14 2 48:8 93:9 44
T15 3 94:8 96:9 1
```

here is the filtered file:

```
$cat filtered_file
12 4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442
54 4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442
95 4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442
```

In this script, I am trying to match a string in the filtered file using line number from the original file.

bash-4.1$ vi comb_rt_ct.ksh

```
#!/bin/bash
rows=1
cols=$(($(cat rt_facts | wc -l) + 1))
declare -a arr #=( $(for i in {1..$cols}; do echo 0; done) )
echo "cols " $cols
for l_num in $(grep '4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442' filtered_file | cut -d" " -f 1)
do
        arr[0]="4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442"
        echo "l_num " $l_num
        cat rt_facts | while IFS=" " read -r lineStr
        do
                line=( $lineStr )
                #echo ${line[*]}
                rt_h=$(echo ${line[2]} | cut -d":" -f 1)
                rt_f=$(echo ${line[3]} | cut -d":" -f 1)

                if (( l_num > $rt_h && l_num < $rt_f )); then
                        echo "rt_h rt_f " $rt_h "  " $rt_f
                        echo "line[*] " ${line[*]}
                        i=${line[1]}
                        echo "i " $i
                        if [[ -z "${arr[$i]}" ]]; then
                                echo "empty"
                                arr[$i]=0
                        fi
                        (( arr[$i]++ ))
                        echo "arr[$i] "${arr[$i]}
                        #echo ${line[0]}
                        break
                fi
        done
        echo
done

echo ${arr[@]}
echo ${arr[*]}
echo ${arr[2]}
```

Here is the output when I run the script:

```
bash-4.1$ sh comb_rt_ct.ksh
cols  4
l_num  12
rt_h rt_f  2    47
line[*]  T5 1 2:8 47:9 44
i  1
empty
arr[1] 1

l_num  54
rt_h rt_f  48    93
line[*]  T14 2 48:8 93:9 44
i  2
empty
arr[2] 1

l_num  95
rt_h rt_f  94    96
line[*]  T15 3 94:8 96:9 1
i  3
empty
arr[3] 1

4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442
4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442
```

bash-4.1$

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your script has a `ksh` extension, a `bash` shebang, and you're running it with `sh`.

Comment: I have added the filtered file. Ksh extension is not the issue but I have updated it anyway to .sh extension.

Answer (score 1):

As @glennjackman has pointed out, the question needs to be updated to provide a minimal, reproducible example; so I'm skipping trying to reverse engineer the intent of the script (or figure out the content of the file named `filtered_file`) and instead focus on one item of interest:

```
cat t_facts | while IFS=" " read
    ...
    <assign_values_to_array>
    ...
done
```

The `| while ...` invokes a subshell; new values are assigned to the `arr[]` array within this subshell.

In `ksh`, when exiting the subshell, the newly updated `arr[]` values are (effectively) passed to the calling/parent process.

In `bash`, when exiting the subshell, the newly updated `arr[]` values are discarded when returning to the calling/parent process.

Because OP's code is running under `bash` (`#!/bin/bash`), the changes to `arr[]` are lost upon exiting the subshell; this in turn means the calling/parent process 'still' has the same initial value in `arr[]`, namely:

```
arr[0]="4046580009982686 05072021 24692161126100379438583 44442"
```

---

---

One method to address this issue, which should work in `ksh` and `bash`:

```
while IFS=" " read
    ...
    <assign_value_to_array>
    ...
done < t_facts
```

This eliminates the subshell invocation and therefore allows the new array assignments to be made in the main process.

---

---

Again, I haven't attempted to understand the overall logic of the script, but fwiw ... I'd suggest OP make the suggested code change to the `while` loop (to eliminate the subshell invocation) to see if the `arr[]` array is populated with the desired results.

Comment: This suggestion worked for #1 issue. Thank you. Do you have a suggestion for #2?